# Telegram Bot - URL of webhook dissapears

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, telegram, webhooks

I have a telegram bot which uses a webhook (API Gateway - AWS). The code of the bot is stored in a lambda and works correctly.

If I use the command `getWebHookInfo` this is what I get:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://mywebhook-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40,"ip_address":"10.100.100.100","allowed_updates":["message","inline_query","callback_query"]}}
```

Then, whenever I send a message the url of the webhook disappears and I don't get any last error message. This is what I get if I use again the `getWebHookInfo` command:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":1,"allowed_updates":["message","inline_query","callback_query"]}}
```

Also, if I do a post request in Postman emulating a Telegram message the code works correctly and I will also receive an answer for the pending message !
It doesn't seems an error of the webhook, and for sure it's not an error of the code of the bot.

What's funny is that for a moment it worked, but it didn't last more than a few minutes... Any help will be appreciated, I'm completely out of ideas!

Comment: With postman you make the same request than the one made by getWebHookInfo ?

Comment: Yes, but the request send by Telegram is different. The getwebhookinfo is just for seing the info of the webhook for a specific bot, is not like sending a message.